# How to display image in AudioPlayerViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, avaudioplayer, sdwebimage

This is the TableViewController with the list of the audios. It successfully grabs all data from firebase and displays in a table. I include a screenshot[image: This is the TableViewController][image: This is the AudioPlayerViewController]

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Combine
import SDWebImage

class ListOfAudioLessonsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    let placeHolderImage = UIImage(named: "placeHolderImage")
    private var viewModel = AudiosViewModel()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
            self.title = "Audio Lessons"
                       
            table.delegate = self
            table.dataSource = self
            
            cancellable = viewModel.$audios.sink { _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    
                    self.table.reloadData()
        }
    }            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

        
        
        // Table
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print("audios count = ", viewModel.audios.count)
            return viewModel.audios.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
            let song = viewModel.audios[indexPath.row]
            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
            cell.textLabel?.text = song.albumName
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = song.name
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            
            
            let imageURL = song.audioImageName
                    cell.imageView?.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
            cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL),
                                        placeholderImage: placeHolderImage,
                                        options: SDWebImageOptions.highPriority,
                                        context: nil,
                                        progress: nil,
            completed: { downloadedImage, downloadException, cacheType, downloadURL in
                if let downloadException = downloadException {
                    print("error downloading the image: \(downloadException.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("successfuly downloaded the image: \(String(describing: downloadURL?.absoluteString))")
    }
})
            
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            let backgroundView = UIView()
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AudioLessonsCellHighlighted")
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)
            cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        
            return cell
}
    
        
        
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 100
            
        }
        
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
      
            // present the player
            let position = indexPath.row
            
            //lessons
            
            guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AudioPlayer") as? AudioPlayerViewController else {
            return
            
        }
            
            vc.paragraphs = viewModel.audios
            vc.position = position
            
        present(vc, animated: true)

    }
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AudioLessonsHighlighted")
            cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
            cell.detailTextLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
           

        }
    }
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is the AudioPlayerViewController. It successfully plays audio from link grabbed from firbase. It shows all the labels but doesn't display the image. The image also should be downloaded from firebase according to the row selected by the user. I succeeded to download and display image in tableviewcontroller but in cannot display AudioPlayerViewController and my question is: How to display image from firebase in AlbumImageview in AudioPlayerViewController?   I include a screenshot

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit
import Combine
import SDWebImage

class AudioPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
                
    private var viewModel = AudiosViewModel()
    public var position: Int = 0
    public var paragraphs: [Audio] = []
    let placeHolderImage = UIImage(named: "placeHolderImage")

   
@IBOutlet var holder: UIView!
var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    var isSeekInProgress = false
    var chaseTime = CMTime.zero
    fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 15
    var playerCurrentItemStatus: AVPlayerItem.Status = .unknown

                // User Interface elements
private let albumImageView: UIImageView = {
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
return imageView
}()
    
private let paragraphNumberLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .light)
label.numberOfLines = 0 // allow line wrap
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
return label
}()
                
private let albumNameLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
label.numberOfLines = 0 // allow line wrap
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
return label
}()
                
private let songNameLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .ultraLight)
label.numberOfLines = 0 // allow line wrap
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
return label
}()
    
private let elapsedTimeLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
label.text = "00:00"
label.numberOfLines = 0
return label
}()
        
private let remainingTimeLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.textAlignment = .left
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
label.textColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
label.text = "00:00"
label.numberOfLines = 0
return label
}()
        
private let playbackSlider: UISlider = {
let v = UISlider()
    v.addTarget(AudioPlayerViewController.self, action: #selector(progressScrubbed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    v.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
v.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
v.thumbTintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
v.minimumValue = 0
v.isContinuous = true
return v
}()
   
    
    

let playPauseButton = UIButton()
    
    
                

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
                    
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture(gesture:)))
    self.playbackSlider.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
                    

let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            }
                catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        
                
if holder.subviews.count == 0 {
    configure()
                    }
                }
                func configure() {
                    // set up player
                    let song = paragraphs[position]
                    
                    let url = URL(string: song.trackURL)
                    let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
                    do {
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
                        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
                        guard url != nil else {
                            print("urls string is nil")
                            return
                        }
   
                        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                        
                        
                        let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
                        
                        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                        
                        remainingTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
                        
                        let currentDuration : CMTime = playerItem.currentTime()
                        
                        let currentSeconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentDuration)
                        
                        elapsedTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: currentSeconds)

                        playbackSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
                       
                        
                        player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
                            
                            if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
                                self.playbackSlider.value = Float(time)
                                
                                self.elapsedTimeLabel.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: time)
                            }
                            
                            let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
                            if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false{
                                print("IsBuffering")
                                self.playPauseButton.isHidden = true
                               
                            } else {
                                // stop the activity indicator
                                print("Buffering completed")
                                
                                self.playPauseButton.isHidden = false
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                        playbackSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AudioPlayerViewController.progressScrubbed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
                        self.view.addSubview(playbackSlider)
                        //subroutine used to keep track of current location of time in audio file
                        guard let player = player else {
                            print("player is nil")
                            return
                        }
                        player.play()
                        
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("error accured")
                    }
                    // set up user interface elements
                    
                    //album cover
albumImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                              y: 20,
                              width: holder.frame.size.width - 40,
                              height: holder.frame.size.width - 40)
                    
                    albumImageView.image = UIImage(named: song.audioImageName)

                    
                    
                    holder.addSubview(albumImageView)
                    
                    //Labels Song name, album, artist
                    albumNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                 y: holder.frame.size.height - 300,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width - 40,
                                                  height: 20)
                    paragraphNumberLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                  y: holder.frame.size.height - 280,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                  height: 20)
                    songNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                  y: holder.frame.size.height - 260,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                  height: 20)
                    playbackSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                  y: holder.frame.size.height - 235,
                                                  width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                  height: 40)
                    elapsedTimeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 25,
                                                    y: holder.frame.size.height - 200,
                                                    width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                    height: 15)
                    remainingTimeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: holder.frame.size.width-60,
                                                      y: holder.frame.size.height - 200,
                                                      width: holder.frame.size.width-20,
                                                      height: 15)
                    songNameLabel.text = song.name
                    albumNameLabel.text = song.albumName
                    paragraphNumberLabel.text = song.paragraphNumber
                    holder.addSubview(songNameLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(albumNameLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(paragraphNumberLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(elapsedTimeLabel)
                    holder.addSubview(remainingTimeLabel)
                    //Player controls
                    let nextButton = UIButton()
                    let backButton = UIButton()
                    let seekForwardButton = UIButton()
                    let seekBackwardButton = UIButton()
                    //frames of buttons
                    playPauseButton.frame = CGRect(x: (holder.frame.size.width - 40) / 2.0,
                                                   y: holder.frame.size.height - 172.5,
                                                   width: 40,
                                                   height: 40)
                    
                    nextButton.frame = CGRect(x: holder.frame.size.width - 70,
                                                   y: holder.frame.size.height - 162.5,
                                                   width: 30,
                                                   height: 20)
                    
                    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 70 - 30,
                                            y: holder.frame.size.height - 162.5,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 20)
                    seekForwardButton.frame = CGRect(x: holder.frame.size.width - 140,
                                                     y: holder.frame.size.height - 167.5,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30)
                    seekBackwardButton.frame = CGRect(x: 110,
                                            y: holder.frame.size.height - 167.5,
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30)
                    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 20,
                                                                y: holder.frame.size.height - 80,
                                                                width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                                height: 30))
                    holder.addSubview(volumeView)
                    //actions of buttons
                    playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapPlayPauseButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBackButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                    nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapNextButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                    seekForwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seekForwardButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                    seekBackwardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(seekBackwardButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                    //styling of buttons
                    playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
                    nextButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "forward.fill"), for: .normal)
                    backButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "backward.fill"), for: .normal)
                    seekForwardButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "goforward.15"), for: .normal)
                    seekBackwardButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "gobackward.15"), for: .normal)
   
                    playPauseButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    nextButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    backButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    seekForwardButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    seekBackwardButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PlayerColors")
                    
                    holder.addSubview(playPauseButton)
                    holder.addSubview(nextButton)
                    holder.addSubview(backButton)
                    holder.addSubview(seekForwardButton)
                    holder.addSubview(seekBackwardButton)
}
    
    @objc func panGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentPoint = gesture.location(in: playbackSlider)
        let percentage = currentPoint.x/playbackSlider.bounds.size.width;
        let delta = Float(percentage) * (playbackSlider.maximumValue - playbackSlider.minimumValue)
        let value = playbackSlider.minimumValue + delta
        playbackSlider.setValue(value, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func progressScrubbed(_ playbackSlider: UISlider!) {
        let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value)
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
        player!.seek(to: targetTime)
        if player!.rate == 0
        {
            player?.play()
        }
    }
    
    func setupNowPlaying() {
      // Define Now Playing Info
      var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
      nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Unstoppable"
      
      if let image = UIImage(named: "artist") {
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
          return image
        }
      }
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player?.currentTime
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = playerItem?.duration
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player?.rate
      
      // Set the metadata
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
    
    func updateNowPlaying(isPause: Bool) {
      // Define Now Playing Info
      var nowPlayingInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo!
      
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player?.currentTime
      nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = isPause ? 0 : 1
      
      // Set the metadata
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
    
    func setupNotifications() {
      let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
      notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                     selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                                     name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification,
                                     object: nil)
      notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                     selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),
                                     name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification,
                                     object: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleRouteChange(notification: Notification) {
      guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let reasonValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt,
        let reason = AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason(rawValue:reasonValue) else {
          return
      }
      switch reason {
      case .newDeviceAvailable:
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        for output in session.currentRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headphones {
          print("headphones connected")
          DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            player?.play()
          }
          break
        }
      case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        if let previousRoute =
          userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey] as? AVAudioSessionRouteDescription {
          for output in previousRoute.outputs where output.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headphones {
            print("headphones disconnected")
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                player?.pause()
            }
            break
          }
        }
      default: ()
      }
    }
    
    @objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
      guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
          return
      }
      
      if type == .began {
        print("Interruption began")
        // Interruption began, take appropriate actions
      }
      else if type == .ended {
        if let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt {
          let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
          if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
            // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
            print("Interruption Ended - playback should resume")
            player?.play()
          } else {
            // Interruption Ended - playback should NOT resume
            print("Interruption Ended - playback should NOT resume")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    @objc func didTapPlayPauseButton() {
        if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                           //pause
                           player?.pause()
                           
                           
                           //show play button
                           playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
                           //shrink image
                           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                               self.albumImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50,
                                                             y: 50,
                                                             width: self.holder.frame.size.width - 100,
                                                             height: self.holder.frame.size.width - 100)
                               
                           })
                           
                       }
                       else {
                           //play
                           player?.play()
                           //show pause button
                           playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill"), for: .normal)
                           
                           //increase image size
                           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                               self.albumImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                                             y: 20,
                                                             width: self.holder.frame.size.width - 40,
                                                             height: self.holder.frame.size.width - 40)
                               
                           })
                           
                           
                   }
                           
                       
                   }

    private func setupView() {
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            holder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            holder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            holder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            holder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

    
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        player?.play()
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
        
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        player?.pause()
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        
    }
    
}
```

This is the structure of the Adio

```
import Foundation

struct Audio {
    let name: String
    let albumName: String
    let paragraphNumber: String
    let audioImageName: String
    let trackURL: String
}
```

This is AudiosViewModel

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore


class AudiosViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var audios = [Audio]()
private var db = Firestore.firestore()


func fetchData() {
    db.collection("audios").addSnapshotListener { [self] (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
    print("No Documents")
    return
}

self.audios = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Audio in
    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
    let albumName = data["albumName"] as? String ?? ""
    let audioImageName = data["audioImageName"] as? String ?? ""
    let paragraphNumber  = data["paragraphNumber"] as? String ?? ""
    let trackURL  = data["trackURL"] as? String ?? ""
              
    print(data)

    
    return Audio(name: name, albumName: albumName, paragraphNumber: paragraphNumber, audioImageName: audioImageName, trackURL: trackURL)
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the image that you wish to display in the detail view controller the same image downloaded from the table view controller or do you need to download a separate image?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same image downloaded from the table view controller. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view model that populates the cells with data, add an `image` property.

```
var image: UIImage?
```

In `cellForRowAt` where you fetch the image, in addition to injecting the image into the cell, save it to the view model.

```
var song = viewModel.audios[indexPath.row]
song.image = fetchedImage
```

Add an image property to the `AudioPlayerViewController` view controller.

```
var mainImage = UIImage(named: "placeHolderImage")
```

In `didSelectRowAt`, inject the detail view controller with the image from the model before presenting it.

```
vc.mainImage = viewModel.image
present(vc, animated: true)
```

There is no need to download the image again if it was just downloaded by the previous view controller. Simply expand your view model to include this image and pass it forward when it comes time to present.

Comment: Now it throws an error: `Cannot find 'fetchedImage' in scope`

Comment: @Vugar in which view controller?

Comment: - in the  `ListOfAudioLessonsTableViewController`

Comment: @Vugar you have to make it part of the model, in the same way you access `song.albumName` in `cell.textLabel?.text = song.albumName`.

Comment: Do I need to add a `image` nember to Video structure as well?

Comment: @Vugar only if you need it. If videos have images also and you're doing the same thing there that you are doing here then yes, you would most likely need to add an image property to `Video`.

Comment: Succeeded! but there is a but. Now I have timing issue. When user taps on `tableviewcell` `AudioPlayerViewController` appears and displays the `placeHolderImage` firstly, then it displays the supposed image only when user goes back to main page and comes back again. How to solve this timing issue?

Comment: Succeeded, I just relocated assigning to property code. And it works. Thank you!